# issue for the share a text on Linkedin.com

Tags: ios, xcode4, linkedin-api, sharekit

I created an application in which I integrate the LinkedIn social site for that some problem aries which describe below.

**Specification**

In project I use the sharekit for the facebook, twitter and linkedIn integration while the most of the working perfectly.

**Problems**

When i pressing the button for sharing a text on LinkedIn for that webview is loaded and inserted username and password into the filed on LinkedIn page.

Then after LinkedIn needs to insert code for the post(like captcha) that can't show into the  webview.

for that the following screen displays into portrait view.
[image]

And following screen for the Landscape view

[image]

but I can't insert the security code into the textbox and press button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

issue solved by me hope may help some one .. . . . .

When this type of the problem screen aries into the integration of the linkedIn in that time just replace the callback url into project which is following also that url put into the LinkedIn app creation callback url as well as.

```
http://linkedin_oauth/success
```

May this solution is useful who aries this problem.

Thanks and Regards
neon samuel

Comment: This seems to be a right solution, but it throws an exception because it somehow makes UIWindow root controller which is not UIViewController

Comment: Now is OAuth Redirect URL, not Integration URL. No callback url on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding (DefaultSHKConfigurator)

```
- (NSString *)modalPresentationStyleForController:(UIViewController *)controller {
    return @"UIModalPresentationFormSheet";
}
```

with **UIModalPresentationPageSheet** instead of **UIModalPresentationFormSheet** in my CustomSHKConfigurator subclass solved similar problem for me for iPad devices